# website incompatible with IE and firefox

Tags: html, css

Guys I am new to XHTML and CSS and for some reason the website I am building looks fine in chrome and safari, but looks totally incomplete on IE and firefox. Is there anything that you can recommend to make it compatible with all the browsers mentioned above?am I missing some syntax?You can also visit at www.alejandrochacon.com

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexone.css"/>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="whole">

        <header id= "top">
            <div id="title"><h1>Jorge Alejandro Chacon</h1></div>
             <div id="quote"><h6></br></br>"One machine can do the work of fifty ordinary men. No machine can do the work of one extraordinary man."
             <br/><br/>Elbert Hubbard</h6></div>
            <div id="pic">
                <a href="resume.pdf"><img src="images/one.jpg" title="See resume"width= 190px height=290px align="middle"/>See my resume</a>
            </div>

        </header>
        <nav id= "navigation">
            <ul>
                <div id="buttons">
                <li><a href="index.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE" >Home</a>
                <li><a href="Edu.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Educational Background</a>
                <li><a href="prof.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Professional Background</a>
                <li><a href="projects.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Projects</a>
                <li><a href="contact.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Contact me</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>

        </nav>
        <div id ="middle_div">
            <section id="mid_section">
                <div id="boxes">
                    <!-- <h1>
                        Leave your information here for a quick reponse:
                    </h1>
                    <br/>
                    <form id="myform" action="userinfo.php" method="post">
                        Name:<input type="text" value="name" name="name1">
                        Email:<input type="email" value="email" name="email">
                        Phone:<input type= "tel" value="phone(opt)" name="phone">
                        <button id="sub">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <span id="result"></span>
                 </div>
                <div id="boxes">-->
                    <h1>
                        Email me at...
                    </h1>
                    <p>For any comments or suggestions please contact me at the email shown below.</br></br>Thank you!</p>
                    <div id=email><a href="mailto:web@alejandrochacon.com"><img src="images/Email.jpg" title="email"width= 200px height=300px align="middle"/>
                    web@alejandrochacon.com</a></div>


                 </div>

            </section>
            <aside id="side_section">
                <h1>News</h1>
                <div id="newbox">

                    <h4><br/>Find me on Linkedin</h4>
                    <p><br/>Hi everyone, I just opened a linkedin profile and I want to make sure you check it out and add me as one of your connections.
                    <br/><br/>Thanks!
                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/jalejandrochacon/">Alejandro's linkedin</a></p>
                </div>
                <div id="newbox">

                    <h4><br/>Online tutorials</h4>
                    <p></br>For those of you who want to learn on your own, take a look at this awesome website to get free education.
                    <a href="http://thenewboston.org/tutorials.php">thenewboston.org</a></p>
                </div>
                <div id="newbox">

                    <h4><br/>Programming help</h4>
                    <p></br>If you have questions or need help in  any type of programming language, find quick answers here.
                    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow.com</a></p>
                </div>

            </aside>
        </div>
        <footer id="bottom">

           <ul>
                <div id="navFooter">
                <li><a href="index.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE" >Home</a>
                <li><a href="Edu.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Educational Background</a>
                <li><a href="prof.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Professional Background</a>
                <li><a href="projects.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Projects</a>
                <li><a href="contact.html" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Contact me</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
           </br>
           Developed by Jorge Chacon 2013
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

h1{
    font: bold 35px tahoma;
    text-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.8) 2px 2px 2px;
    width: 400px;
}
h4,h5{
    font-family: tahoma;
}
h6{

    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px;
    float: right;
}

header, section,footer,aside,nav{
    display: block;/*make sure is compatible with all browsers*/
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    background-image:url(images/gray.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#whole{

    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
#top{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#759600,#B2CC01);
    border: 4px solid white;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;

}

#navigation{
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 40px;

}
#navigation li,a{

    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 4px;
    font: bold 14px tahoma;
    color: #759600;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;

}
a:hover {
    color:#1ec7e6;
}
#java{
    list-style: none;
}
#middle_div{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}

#mid_section{

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    height: auto;
    margin:5px;

}

#email, img{
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;

    }
#epic{
    padding-left: 100px;
}

#side_section{
    border: 1px solid #759600;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    margin: 5px;
    padding:20px;
    height: auto;

}
#bottom{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #759600;
    color:white;
}
#boxes{


    border: 1px solid #759600;
    margin:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    background: #D3D3D3;
}

#pic{
    background: #D3D3D3;
    width: 17%;
    height: 86%;
    float: right;
    border:3px solid white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 7px 7px 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, background 1s;


}

#pic:hover{
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    background: #1ec7e6;


}
p{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: justify;


}
#title{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#classes{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-family: tahoma;
}

img{
    display: block;
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto

}

iframe{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
#newbox{
    border-top: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: black;
}
#pic a{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

#navFooter li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

MODIFIED CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

h1{
    font: bold 35px tahoma;
    text-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.8) 2px 2px 2px;
    width: 400px;
}
h4,h5{
    font-family: tahoma;
}
h6{

    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px;
    float: right;
}

header, section,footer,aside,nav{
    display: block;/*make sure is compatible with all browsers*/
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box, -moz-box, -ms-box, -o-box, box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -ms-box-pack: center;
    -o-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    background-image:url(images/gray.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#whole{

    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: -webkit-box, -moz-box, -ms-box, -o-box, box;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -ms-box-orient: vertical;
    -o-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-box-flex: 1;
    -o-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
}
#top{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#759600,#B2CC01) ;
    border: 4px solid white;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;

}

#navigation{
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 40px;

}
#navigation li,a{

    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 4px;
    font: bold 14px tahoma;
    color: #759600;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    -moz-transition:5px;
    -ms-transition: 5px;
    -o-transition: 5px;
    transition: 5px;

}
a:hover {
    color:#1ec7e6;
}
#java{
    list-style: none;
}
#middle_div{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    -o-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;

}

#mid_section{

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-box-flex: 1;
    -o-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    height: auto;
    margin:5px;

}

#email, img{
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    }
#epic{
    padding-left: 100px;
}

#side_section{
    border: 1px solid #759600;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    margin: 5px;
    padding:20px;
    height: auto;

}
#bottom{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #759600;
    color:white;
}
#boxes{


    border: 1px solid #759600;
    margin:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    -ms-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    -o-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    background: #D3D3D3;
}

#pic{
    background: #D3D3D3;
    width: 17%;
    height: 86%;
    float: right;
    border:3px solid white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 7px 7px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 7px 7px 7px;
    -ms-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    -o-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, background 1s;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, background 1s;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, background 1s;
    -o-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, background 1s;
    transition: -webkit-transform 2s, background 1s;

}

#pic:hover{
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    background: #1ec7e6;


}
p{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: justify;


}
#title{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#classes{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-family: tahoma;
}

img{
    display: block;
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto

}

iframe{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
#newbox{
    border-top: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: black;
}
#pic a{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

#navFooter li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific with the problem - you may experience it one way, others with different browser versions/patches/OSes may see it in another.

Comment: You might want to work on some of the markup errors too: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Falejandrochacon.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are only using the -webkit- vendor prefix. You need to copy all those css values and add -moz- for firefox, -ms- for internet explorer and -o- for opera. Also, include a copy of that line of css without the prefix just for good measure.

Example:

```
body{
width: 100%;
display: box, -webkit-box, -moz-box, -ms-box, -o-box;
box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-pack: center;
-ms-box-pack: center;
-o-box-pack: center;
background-image:url(images/gray.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I would venture to add they should be in descending order, with the unprefixed version at the top. That way, different browsers will override the rule in the way they are supposed to.

Comment: Can you show me a little example of what you mean? I have an idea,but I just want to double check. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @icedwater totally agree, but you can also include it at the end so that the browser at least tries to handle it's prefix before it resorts to the un-prefixed code

Comment: @achacon does that example help?

Comment: Either way works, I was looking at it as modifying a baseline, you are trying to support the properties as they are mentioned I guess?

Comment: @ColinMcGrath I tried the above and it fixed some of the issues . However, IE and mozilla are still making the website look in pretty bad shape. I am going to add the modified CSS. Can you please guide me a little more?

Comment: @ColinMcGrath I think the point of listing prefixed rules first is because you want the un-prefixed to be rendered (to "win") if possible. Running the un-prefixed version is not a "resort" but rather what you should prefer. The un-prefixed syntax is where all browsers are headed as they are being standardized.

Comment: @Achacon First of all, you missed adding a couple prefixes in some places of your code (check the background on your #text css). Secondly some of the items in your code need prefixes and have none. Add them to all your border-radius css.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure that will be the only thing you consider as 'not working', but you should first add webkit equivalents in your css file (webkit only refers to chrome, if you want to make it work else where, you'll have to have its 'moz' and other counterparts.

Comment: Webkit refers to Chrome or Safari or Konquorer, or anything that uses the *WebKit* engine.

Comment: Thanks for the accuracy, knew about the engine, but not about Konquorer. But my point was that he still misses the other prefixes as Colin said just before I did :)